# How to implement autocomplete function in android with google map

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete

I am using this code in my XML project.

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                    />
```

but I can't import `com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment`
What should I do to implement autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

For using autocomplete you need to add following dependency as well

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.6.0'
```

For more details follow following links
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

https://medium.com/skillhive/android-google-places-autocomplete-feature-bb3064308f05